# How to deploy a library with Java EE 6 / Glassfish 3.x

Tags: java-ee-6, glassfish-3, ear, maven-3

I have got an EAR with two plain libraries. One of them being scala-library. If I deploy the EAR with Netbeans it works as expected. While this is OK for development the final product should be deployable via the command line. For this I use:

```
asadmin --user … deploy --upload ./target/…-ear.ear
```

which fails with:

```
org.glassfish.api.admin.CommandException: remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app […-ear] : C:\Work\Workspa
ces\…\Glassfish\…\applications\scala-library-2.8.0.jar. Please see server.log for more details.
Befehl deploy fehlgeschlagen.
```

Searching the net I found out that handling libraries have become more strict with Java EE 6 / Glassfish 3.x and that it is not enough to add them to the `lib` folder inside the ear any more. Only the author neglected to mention what is needed now.

I found new `<module><java>` entries for the `META-INF\application.xml` — but that did not help either:

```
  <module>
    <java>scala-library-2.8.0.jar</java>
  </module>
```

So the question: Does anybody know what you have to do to add libraries to an EAR file for Java EE 6 / Glassfish 3.x?

PS: I use Maven to build - if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it seems I found the solution myself (again). After adding a `library-directory` entry to the **end** of the `META-INF\application.xml` the deployment runs thou:

```
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

The strange thing is that `lib` the default for `library-directory`. So I guess it must be a bug in Glassfish itself not handling the default correctly. If you use Maven make sure to use `bundleDir` in your `pom.xml` so that the libs are place in the right place:

```
        <jarModule>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
          <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
        </jarModule>
```